# Jest not working with fs/promises typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to add jest to my typescript project for testing, but when I run jest, it keeps giving me the error

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'fs/promises' from 'src/path/to/file'

    Require stack:
      src/path/to/file
      test/test.ts

    > 3 | import fsp from 'fs/promises';

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:311:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/path/to/file.ts:3:1)
```

The program itself runs fine, but whenever I try to run jest on it, it runs into this issue. I've tried adding `jest.mock('fs');`, which didn't help, and adding `jest.mock('fs/promises');` gives the same error in the test file.

I've read that certain versions of Node don't support `'fs/promises'` and instead need `require('fs').promises`, which I've tried and still doesn't work (I'm on Node version 12).

How can I configure jest to be able to load `'fs/promises'`? I've included my `jest.config.js` file below:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '/out/',
  ],
  moduleDirectories: [
    '.',
    'node_modules'
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'ts',
    'tsx',
    'js',
    'jsx'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show the minimal, reproducible code

Comment: Add ts-jest to your project.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-jest

Comment: @slideshowp2 unfortunately I can't provide the project itself, but I believe the issue is that jest is interpreting 'fs/promises' as a folder in the file system when it's actually a module, so I'll have to somehow let jest know about this, but I don't know where/how to include this note

Comment: @StevenScott ts-jest has been added to my project, but this issue is still there.

Comment: @slideshowp2 Just solved this issue. Ended up just adding a map from `'fs/promises'` to `<rootDir>/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs` using `moduleNameMapper`

Answer (score 3):

Turns out Jest is interpreting `'fs/promises'` as a folder in the file system, which is incorrect as this is an API from the fs module. To fix this, simply add

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
  "fs/promises": "<rootDir>/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs"
}
```

to `jest.config.js` to tell Jest to map the module `'fs/promises'` to the file `<rootDir>/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs`, or wherever the fs module is defined in your file system.