# Why is my resetAllMocks not working in jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking

The second expect(fs.writeFile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) (in describe('Guid for MPX') returns an error because the writeFile has been called twice. In theory, jest.ResetAllMocks should take care of this but it doesn’t.

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

const guidForMpxInvalid = require('../json/guid-for-Mpx-invalid.json')
const data = require('../../../data/sandbox-data-model.json');

jest.mock('fs', () => ({
  promises: {
    writeFile: jest.fn(),
  },
}));

const {
  writeData,
  createGuidForMpx,
  createMpxForGuid,
} = require('../app/transform');

const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../wiremock/stubs/mappings');

describe('Write file', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('should write a file', async () => {
    const result = await writeData(guidForMpxInvalid, 'guid-for-Mpx-invalid-Mpx.json');
    expect(result).toEqual('guid-for-Mpx-invalid-Mpx.json written');
    expect(fs.writeFile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});

describe('Guid for MPX', () => {
  it('should create JSON file for the GUID of a particular MPX', async ()=>{
    const result = await createGuidForMpx(data.Customers[0].guid, data.Customers[0].Customer_Overlays.core.Personal_Details.MPX);
    expect(result).toEqual('guid-for-Mpx-AB123456B.json written');
    expect(fs.writeFile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

The code being called:

```
const writeData = async (data, file) => {
  const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../wiremock/stubs/mappings');

  try {
    fs.writeFile(`${directoryPath}/${file}`, data);
    return `${file} written`
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

Comment: `beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });`
Try this out.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem until I placed `jest.resetAllMocks();` inside `afterEach` like so:

```
afterEach(() => {
  jest.resetAllMocks();
});
```

Comment: Changing to afterEach does work to an extent but...

The expect after the 2nd call to writeFile now gives me 1 as expected and required. However, I have a 3rd call (which I didn't include in the post) which gives me the same problem as before - except its now saying writeFile's been called twice rather than 3 times.

Comment: I have tested the code in your example on my end and it actually appears to work fine for both ```beforeEach``` and ```afterEach````. The problem is likely to be on the actual code that you are testing.

Comment: I've added the code being call to the posting. Thanks.

Comment: I have replicated your code and it still works fine on my end :/ it has to be something else

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this working by creating a spy for the writefile at the start of each test and clearing it when the test is done:

```
it('should write a file', async () => {
    const writeFileSpy = jest.spyOn(fs, 'writeFile');
    const result = await writeData(guidForMPXInvalid, 'guid-for-mpx-invalid-mpx.json');
    expect(result).toEqual('guid-for-mpx-invalid-mpx.json written');
    expect(writeFileSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    writeFileSpy.mockClear();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here. I had to use spyOn as well, which is probably better practice.

All should beware when not using spyOn with complex libraries, double check that your reset works, but safe practice is to manually restore the function you mocked.

There is an issue it seems, perhaps because how fs/promises is included. `fs.promises` is a Getter function and is lazy loaded from `internal/fs/promises`, and jest is seemingly unable to clean lazy loaded modules with `jest.resetModules`?

[image: console.log of fs]

See related note by @john-james regarding `moduleNameMapper`:

[Jest not working with fs/promises typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930375/jest-not-working-with-fs-promises-typescript)

Another documented error with resetModules():

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11632